# Import csv file into SQL Server hosted in Amazon RDS using pyodbc

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pyodbc

I'm trying to import csv file to fill up the database that is hosted inside the Amazon RDS server, I'm using pyodbc to import the csv file.

Here is my code

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

stock_table = pd.read_csv("/Users/xxx/Documents/Web Scraping/stocks_table.csv")
stock_table.head()

df = pd.DataFrame(stock_table)
print(df)

server = 'xxx.xyxy.xxx.rds.amazonaws.com'
database = 'database'
username = 'username'
password = 'admin'

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)

cursor = cnxn.cursor()

# Create Table
cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE stocks (Date datetime, Close float(64), Volume float(64), Open float(64), High float(64), Low float(64), stockSymbol nvarchar(50), stock_description_id int, sector nvarchar(80), industry nvarchar(80), one_year_target float, exchange nvarchar(20), percentageChange float(64), priceChange float(64))')

# Insert DataFrame to Table
for row in df.itertuples():
    cursor.execute('''
                INSERT INTO database.dbo.stocks (Date, Close, Volume, Open, High, Low, stockSymbol,
                stock_description_id, sector, industry, one_year_target, exchange, percentageChange, priceChange)
                VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
                ''',
                    row.Date, 
                    row.Close,
                    row.Volume,
                    row.Open,
                    row.High,
                    row.Low,
                    row.stockSymbol,
                    row.stock_description_id,
                    row.sector,
                    row.industry, 
                    row.one_year_target,
                    row.exchange,
                    row.percentageChange,
                    row.priceChange
                )
conn.commit()
```

But when i try to commit it, it shows this error

```
Error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-df4a64bb6bf1> in <module>
      4 password = 'admin'
      5 
----> 6 cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
      7 
      8 cursor = cnxn.cursor()

Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

Is there anyone that could help with this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the ODBC driver, view installation documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15